# How do you animate a Rigify character?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I'm in pose mode, in the animation tab, the Rigify character is all at the default pose and default location. I make the animation range from 1 to 20.

On frame 1, I select the root bone I press i and choose location, a keyframe appears. 
On frame 20, I select and move the root bone, I press i and choose location, a keyframe appears.

I press the spacebar nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

[UPDATE]

I did some more research and  what is preventing my character from moving is when you convert a bone to a wiggle bone. Without everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not all bone automation using drivers and add-ons will work when rendering or might interfere with bone rendering animation.

In pose mode select all bones then go to

Pose> Animation> Bake Action> OK

This will disable all built in automation but will assure that your animation looks identical in your renders as in the viewport.